# ADT with for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I have an use case where I need to use for comprehension with ADT in Scala. I could write the same code using flatMaps but it seems a bit unreadable. Below is the piece of code.

```
case class MovieRecord(movie: Movie,
                       screenId: String,
                       availableSeats: Int,
                       reservedSeats: Option[Int] = None) {
  def movieInfo = new MovieInfoResponse(movie.imdbId, screenId, movie.title, availableSeats, reservedSeats.getOrElse(0))
}


sealed trait MovieBookingInformation
case class MovieBookingInformationFetched(bookMovie: MovieRecord) extends MovieBookingInformation
case object MovieBookingInformationFetchError extends MovieBookingInformation


def modifyBooking(reserveMovie: MovieSelected): Future[String] = {
 fetchRecordByImdbAndScreenId(reserveMovie.imdbId, reserveMovie.screenId) flatMap {
    case MovieBookingInformationFetched(m) if (m.availableSeats > 0) =>
      updateSeatReservationByImdbAndScreenId(m.copy(availableSeats = m.availableSeats - 1, reservedSeats = Some(m.reservedSeats.getOrElse(0) + 1))) flatMap {
        case MovieBookingUpdated(updatedMovieBooking) =>
          Future.successful(s"One seat reserved at Screen - ${updatedMovieBooking.screenId}")
        case MovieBookingUpdateFailed =>
          Future.successful(s"Movie seat reservation failed at screen ${reserveMovie.screenId}")
      }
    case MovieBookingInformationFetched(m) =>
      Future.successful(s"Sorry! No more seats available for ${m.movie.title} at Screen - ${m.screenId}")
    case MovieBookingInformationFetchError => Future.successful(s"No movie with IMDB ID ${reserveMovie.imdbId} found at ${reserveMovie.screenId}")
  }
}
```

In the above code, the next method is invoked on a resultant ADT content and result of if statement. How do I include the if statement in the for-comprehension to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put pattern matching and `if` statements in a for comprehension on `Future`:

```
for {
  MovieBookingInformationFetched(m) <- future1
  if m.availableSeats > 0
  MovieBookingUpdated(updatedMovieBooking) <- future2(m)
} yield updatedMovieBooking
```

However, this will be translated into `Future.filter`, so if the predicate is not satisfied, or the pattern cannot be matched, you'll end up with

```
Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("Future.filter predicate was not satisfied")
```

You can then catch this failure in a `recover` statement, after the for-comp. The problem is that you want to catch three different "errors": the fact that there are no more available seats, the fact that `fetchRecordByImdbAndScreenId` can return a `MovieBookingInformationFetchError`, and the fact that `updateSeatReservationByImdbAndScreenId` can return a `MovieBookingUpdateFailed`.

You won't be able to dissociate between these three using only for comprehension, unless you define custom exceptions, instead of custom result types (and recover these exceptions afterwards).

Comment: Thanks @Cyrille Corpet ! Much appreciated! I think I am good to go now... Is it good to use the flatMap I have used in this situation or I should go for the for-comprehension instead? Thanks again

Comment: Personally, I think you should always use a for-comprehension, unless all you want to do is _map_ or _flatMap_. As soon as you combine these together, possibly with _filter_, it becomes very difficult to understand from the next reader's point of view. Therefore, in such cases, use for-comprehension. Bear in mind of course that the first phase of the compiler immediately converts for comprehensions into map/flatMap/filter expressions -- so they are entirely equivalent.

Comment: Personally, I'd write what you put inside your flatmap as a helper function, and do a for comprehension